# Copy Stamp of 'Photoshop CS2' doesn't work under LMDE with Crossover 13

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, adobe-photoshop, wine

i managed to install PS CS2 with Crossover Linux under Linux Mint Debian Edition
and now every tool works fine except for one the copy stamp and this is rather important
for me because i edit a lot of scanned documents. I'm using Crossover 13 and the exact problem
is if i choose a section with the 'alt'-key pressed and a leftclick and then try copy
it always gives me the error that i have to choose a source area even if i have already chosen one.

Screenshot: http://abload.de/img/errork6o1q.png

Is there any wine library i have do install to get this working or is there no way to fix this?

**Problem solved:**

The solution is really easy i just had to go to 'System settings' -> 'Windows' and set the key to another:

Screenshot: http://abload.de/img/error_solve3yljw.png

Best Regards

Comment: Do you have paid support from Crossover?  Did you try contacting their support?

Comment: Now i use the trial and so think that i'll not get support from them. I'll buy it if CS2 works normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

The solution is really easy i just had to go to 'System settings' -> 'Windows' and set the key to another:

Screenshot: http://abload.de/img/error_solve3yljw.png

Best Regards